# Getting Java.Lang.RuntimeException error - No LinkInfo is found in the bindings, could not retrieve ComponentLinkInfo

Tags: 2011, content-delivery

I am getting an error intermittently on different pages and the same page do not throw the error when i refresh it. The error detail is as below.

```
Java.Lang.RuntimeException

[RuntimeException]
Codemesh.JuggerNet.NTypeValue.Throw)Int64 inst) + 514
Codemesh.JuggerNet.JavaClass.ThrowTypedException(Int64 inst) +1243
Codemesh.JuggerNet.JavaMethod.CallString(JavaProxy jpo, JavaMethodArgument args)
Com.Tridion.Linking.ComponentLink.GetLinkAsString(String sourcePageUri, String targetComponentUri, strin................
```

When i looked into the log files cd_core the details are as below

```
2013-06-21 17:54:26,948 ERROR ComponentLink - Error while constructing linking: null
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
    at com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.init(ComponentLink.java:124) ~[cd_linking.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.<init>(ComponentLink.java:86) ~[cd_linking.jar:na]
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Fatal error, unable to load the StorageManagerFactory
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:90) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<clinit>(StorageManagerFactory.java:58) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    ... 2 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.tridion.configuration.ConfigurationException: JDBC Driver/Datasource class could not be found, com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource, com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource
    at com.tridion.storage.util.JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.registerJDBCDataSource(JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.java:65) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.util.JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.configure(JDBCDataSourceBeanConfigurer.java:42) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.util.SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.configure(SpringContextDynamicConfigurer.java:33) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.configuration.SpringConfigurationLoader.configure(SpringConfigurationLoader.java:26) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.configuration.step.ConfigurationStepLoader.configure(ConfigurationStepLoader.java:47) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.configure(StorageManagerFactory.java:139) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.services.BaseService.<init>(BaseService.java:107) ~[cd_core.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.<init>(StorageManagerFactory.java:106) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory.reloadInstance(StorageManagerFactory.java:86) ~[cd_datalayer.jar:na]
    ... 3 common frames omitted
2013-06-21 17:54:26,954 ERROR ComponentLink - No LinkInfo is found in the bindings, could not retrieve ComponentLinkInfo
2013-06-21 18:06:24,835 ERROR ComponentLink - Error while constructing linking: Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.tridion.storage.StorageManagerFactory
    at com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.init(ComponentLink.java:124) ~[cd_linking.jar:na]
    at com.tridion.linking.ComponentLink.<init>(ComponentLink.java:86) ~[cd_linking.jar:na]
2013-06-21 18:06:24,835 ERROR ComponentLink - No LinkInfo is found in the bindings, could not retrieve ComponentLinkInfo
```

As the error states the application is not able to find JDBC driver/datasource, In that case it should throw error always but this is not the case and this error was caught only once for each page and the next refresh displayed the correct page. (Also we found this issue while browsing on one machine on other machine we never got this error, though i know it has nothing to do with the client machine but need to  confirm).  Please advice.

Comment: Can you please provide more information: 1) Which Java version you are using 2) Which OS your CMS is installed on to 3) Which browser you are using on the concerning client and is the browser have js enabled

Comment: Hi Pankaj, Java version is 1.6.0_41. CMS is installed on Windows Server 2008 R2. We have checked on IE and Chrome but cannot replicate it. C:\Windows\system32>java -version
java version "1.6.0_41"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_41-b02)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 20.14-b01, mixed mode)

C:\Windows\system32>

Comment: Might be quite vague, but whenever this happens, check for resource utilization on the Server and Client machine. By the way, does the machine in concern is lacking in RAM (or is running with a bit outdated hardware) as compared to other machines?

Comment: By "On one machine" i mean the QA Machine, we are getting this error on only one QA machine (but logically the client machine has nothing to do with the error). The server side configuration is quite good and updated one.

Answer (score 4):

Check the sqljdbc4.jar in the bin folder on your Content Delivery setup and ensure this is not corrupted; may be you can think of comparing it with the one available on the environment where the error is not coming or even may be replacing from there to your QA environment

Also, compare/verify that lib folder in your Content Delivery setup is not using incompatible JARs (32-bit-64-bit incompatibility) - specifically sqljdbc related jars

Comment: But in that case it should have thrown this error every time and not intermittently.

Comment: Restart all your Tridion related Services and DCOM+ and the App Pool for CM and HttpUpload; if it still comes intermittently, Contact the SDL Tridion Support

Answer (score 2):

It may sound far fetched, but are all your cd_*_conf.xml in order or is it being messed with in terms of encoding or intermittent reads by some unknown process?

I'm saying this because the log also states that it can't find LinkInfo bindings (which will normally be in cd_storage_conf.xml).

Answer (score -2):

There is some sort of new permissioning issue that is going on.

Or maybe permissioning has changed?

Maybe you are using a different username/usergroup?